# Is the difference in trace lengths why my RTC isnt working?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, high-frequency, rtc

I am using the PCF8523TS RTC with a 32.768 kHz Crystal. I have tested the smaller package which worked fine with the [Adafruit module](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pcf8523-real-time-clock/), but I can't seem to get it to work with the TS package. I either get garbage values or my clock doesnt change at all, depending on what I set the STOP register to.

Does it have to do with faulty PCB layout on my part? Is it because I have slightly different trace lengths going to the crystal?

Also, I accidentally used a slightly larger footprint for my crystal, so two of the back NC pins are left without being soldered to the board. They dont connect to any pins, but is it important that those are connected to a pad for some reason?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't looked at the suggested circuit, but shouldn't there be some capacitors on the crystal lines? Depends on what crystal you used...

Comment: Also, do you have the pull up resistors on the SCL and SDA lines?

Comment: What is the exact PN of your crystal? Is it designed for one of the two load capacitance values that the PCF8523 can provide?

Comment: Are you sure you mounted the crystal correctly? Also, your VSS (gnd) trace is hardly qualified as ground. And C2 can't be found nowhere in the proper proximity. So there are a lot of problems with your layout, and the difference in trace length is definitely not one of them.

Comment: I bet the pads used are on diagonal corners

Comment: @RonBeyer The adafruit schematic didnt have any capacitors on the crystal lines so I didnt put any either. And yes I have 4.7k ohm pull ups on the I2C lines.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am unsure of the part number. I just used the only crystal we have in stock its markings read "32C641" if that helps. However, I did try swapping the crystals I have on had with the one on the Adafruit board and it still worked so I dont think the crystal being used is the issue.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Well I used a footprint too large for the crystal so I couldnt mount the back legs, but they dont connect to anything anyways so I dont think thats the issue.  I will move C2 closer (its just past R1) and the whole thing is also a ground plane but are there any other major layout changes I need to make?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Im fairly certain the pads are not on opposing corners based on the Adafruit board diagram and my testing.

Comment: OK many SMD resonators are made this way but Fox , Citizen are not and I can only guess what you used